# Parsing an unusual http response with Angular, RxJS in Facade pattern

Tags: angular, rxjs, facade

I have a Back-End API that returns data in the following structure:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": // Can basically be anything.. object, array, string, etc...
}
```

The thing is, I'm really confused about how all this is supposed to work with such a nested payload.

Would love a little more guidance regarding how to implement this abomination within my design pattern and how to do it right.

I have the following weapons in my arsenal:

**APIResponse - Model**

```
export default interface APIResponse {
    code: number;
    message: string;
    data?: any;
}
```

---

**NetworkService - Service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class NetworkService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    private _formatErrors(error: any) {
        return throwError(error);
    }

    get(environment: string, path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<APIResponse> {
        return this.http.get<APIResponse>(`${environment}${path}`, { params }).pipe(catchError(this._formatErrors));
    }
}
```

---

**PostsAPI**

I'm stuck exactly here. How do I convert the `APIResponse`'s `data` attribute to `Post[]` Observable?

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsAPI {
    // Lifecycle
    constructor(private _network: NetworkService) { }

    // API Methods
    getAllPosts(page: number = 1, limit: number = 10): Observable<Post[]> {
        return this._network.get(GlobalAPI.baseURL, `${GlobalAPI.endpoints.posts.base}?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`); // Obviously I have a type mismatch here and I'm doing it all wrong.
    }
}
```

---

**PostsFacade**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsFacade {
    posts$: Observable<Post[]>;

    // Lifecycle
    constructor(private _postsAPI: PostsAPI) {
        this._postsAPI.getAllPosts().subscribe(response => this.posts$ = response.data.posts); // Obviously I have a type mismatch here and I'm doing it all wrong.
    }
}
```

---

**HomeComponent - The page that displays the posts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    posts$ = this._postsFacade.posts$;

    // Lifecycle
    constructor(private _postsFacade: PostsFacade) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.posts$); // Returns undefined
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On your `getAllPosts` function you can use `map` operator to only return `data` Or you can do it on `this._postsAPI.getAllPosts().pipe(map(...))` in your facade as well. Also your facade is wrong, it should be `this.posts$ = this._postsAPI.getAllPosts()....` without subscribe otherwise `posts$` should not be type of observable. Then you can use `async` pipe on your template.

Comment: I have had to deal with the same generic result pattern for API responses where I work. I don't care for them either because HTTP already gives you a status code and provides a framework for error responses. Answer upcoming...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to unwrap the ApiResponse and handle errors (logging, showing a popup to the user, etc.) all within the NetworkService. Each business entity service can call the network service and benefit from that logic.

And as mentioned in a comment, `this.posts$` in your PostsFacade should be an observable (or so you indicate with your '$'), so don't subscribe there. That would let you use an async pipe in a component template to subscribe/unsubscribe automatically. Otherwise...

```js
posts: Post[];

ngOnInit() {
  this._postsApi.getAllPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your PostsFacade you should not subscribe to the observable because posts$ will not be of type Observable then.
PostsFacade:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsFacade {
    posts$: Observable<Post[]>;

    // Lifecycle
    constructor(private _postsAPI: PostsAPI) {
        this.posts$ = this._postsAPI.getAllPosts()
    }
}
```

Now to convert the APIResponses data attribute to Post[] use [rxjs map operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) like follows:
 PostsApi:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsAPI {
    // Lifecycle
    constructor(private _network: NetworkService) { }

    // API Methods
    getAllPosts(page: number = 1, limit: number = 10): Observable<Post[]> {
        return this._network.get(GlobalAPI.baseURL, `${GlobalAPI.endpoints.posts.base}?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`).pipe(map(apiResponse => responseToPosts(apiResponse)));
    }
}
```

With `responseToPosts(apiResponse:APIResponse):Post[]` a function which converts your apiResponse to Post[]